# How to set the engineering notation as default in calc?

Tags: calc

In `calc`, I can switch to the engineering notation by pressing `d e`. But how do I make that a default?

I can store the `calc` defaults in the file specified in the `calc-settings-file` variable but I can't find the elisp required to change the default notation to engineering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution as soon as I posted the question ..

### Solution

In my `init.el`:

```
(require 'calc)
(setq calc-settings-file (concat user-emacs-directory "/setup-calc-defaults.el"))
```

In my `setup-calc-defaults.el`:

```
(setq calc-float-format '(eng 0))
```

The defaults don't become effective right-away. Without worrying about what all packages I might need to `require` once again, I simply restarted emacs.

---

From `lisp/calc/calc.el`

```
(defcalcmodevar calc-float-format '(float 0)
  "Format to use for display of floating-point numbers in calc-mode.
Must be a list of one of the following forms:
 (float 0)      Floating point format, display full precision.
 (float N)      N > 0: Floating point format, at most N significant figures.
 (float -N)     -N < 0: Floating point format, calc-internal-prec - N figs.
 (fix N)        N >= 0: Fixed point format, N places after decimal point.
 (sci 0)        Scientific notation, full precision.
 (sci N)        N > 0: Scientific notation, N significant figures.
 (sci -N)       -N < 0: Scientific notation, calc-internal-prec - N figs.
 (eng 0)        Engineering notation, full precision.
 (eng N)        N > 0: Engineering notation, N significant figures.
 (eng -N)       -N < 0: Engineering notation, calc-internal-prec - N figs.")
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Float-Formats.html also notes that: "It is important to distinguish between the current precision and the current display format. After the commands C-u 10 p and C-u 6 d n the Calculator computes all results to ten significant figures but displays only six."